# PHPUnit Dry Run or Discover Test without executing

Tags: php, phpunit

I would like to write a script that "discovers" PHPUnit test in a given folder.

Currently I can execute:

```
phpunit .
```

And all my test names are shown however they are executed which can take quite a bit of time.

What I would like is the ability to view which test I have in a project without actually executing the test. In a format similar to

```
ExampleTest::testNameHere
```

Is this possible?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for:

[`--list-tests`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.4/textui.html?highlight=list-tests)

Answer (score 0):

```
/* phpunit/php-file-iterator */
$iteratorFactory = new File_Iterator_Factory();

$paths = array(
    /* testsuite path */
    '/var/www/project/tests/unit/phpUnit/',
);

$suffixes = array(
    'Test.php',
);
$iterator = $iteratorFactory->getFileIterator($paths, $suffixes);

foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    $fileName = $file->getFileName();
    $path = $file->getPathName();

    // you should use autoloader
    require_once $path;

    // build className, according to your file structure
    $class = preg_replace('/\.php/', '', $fileName);

    $refrlection = new ReflectionClass($class);
    $methods = $refrlection->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);
    foreach ($methods as $method) {

        // test* is test method
        if (preg_match('/^test[A-Z]/', $method->getName())) {
            echo $refrlection->getName() . ':' . $method->getName();
            echo PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code that detects if a file contains:

- A class that inherits the PHPUnit base class for test classes (sorry, don't have the name in front of me)
- Methods in that class that start with 'test'

should do the trick.